# PC 1 can't see PC 2 on network but PC 2 can see PC 1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I have two laptops on the company domain. Both are using a physical connection (not Wi-Fi). One is freshly imaged with Windows 8.1 and the other is the old laptop (also Windows 8.1) being replaced. I am a local admin on both PCs.

I intended to browse to the new PC from the old PC and copy over the user's documents, however it errored out saying `"Windows cannot access \\\hostname\c$. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network.... Error Code 0x80004005 Unspecified Error"`. I tired `ipconfig \flushdns` but no luck. I then went to the new laptop and tried browsing to the old laptop, and it worked just fine. I was also able to browse to both PCs from my laptop. I was able to get everything transferred over, but I'm wondering why one computer would refuse to see another?

So to summarize:

```
Old => New FAIL
Old => other computers SUCCESS
New => Old SUCCESS
New => other computers SUCCESS
Other computers => New SUCCESS
Other computers => Old SUCCESS
```

Comment: The New labtop inbound firewall could be an issue.  Can you ping from old to new?

Comment: No, we were not able to ping from old to new (but new to old worked). The firewall is a good idea, but I didn't check it because I was able to connect to the new laptop from two other computers.